# How to Compile a Svelte file to JavaScript from the Command line?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm new to [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/). Quick question:

**Is there a CLI for the Svelte compiler, and how do I access it?**

I understand Svelte has a preconfigured setup that uses rollup and what not
for building an app. That's all good, but I only need the CLI for transforming
a `svelte` file to pure `js` file.  Something like:

`svelte compile  input.svelte --out=out.js`

**Update**
It seems like there is no CLI for the Svelte compiler.
However, a brief outline of the compilation process is available [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/site/content/docs/04-compile-time.md). In particular,the following code snippet, which can be
used to build CLI.

```js
result: {
    js,
    css,
    ast,
    warnings,
    vars,
    stats
} = svelte.compile(source: string, options?: {...})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Svelte 3 there is no official CLI.

You'll either write one:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { compile } from "svelte/compiler";
import fs from "node:fs";

const filename = process.argv[2];
const source = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8');
const result = compile(source, { filename });
process.stdout.write(result.js.code);
```

and customize that script to your exact needs (Custom [compile options](https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-compile)
and/or run additional [preprocessors](https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-preprocess) for TypeScript support etc)

But most cases an existing build tool is a better option
and for most build tools there is [plugin (vite)](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte) or [loader (webpack)](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-loader) available for Svelte.

Comment: Would this consider compile options from somewhere or could we pass compile options somehow. Use-case is to create a custom element from an otherwise existing component within a Sveltekit project.

Comment: 'compile()' will get compile options as second argument, I just checked. So we could expose some options as CLI tool arguments and pass them to the compiler.

Comment: compile's first argument is the source code string, not filename
https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-compile

Comment: Oops, it created a component that just displays the filename . 
I've updated the answer so it loads and uses the source from the filename.