# Can svelte be compiled prior to deploying to AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, svelte

I already have API endpoints on AWS API Gateway. My use case is static delivery of an SPA built in Svelte. AWS Cloudfront would deliver the SPA to users and user behavior therein would trigger Fetch to ping the established endpoints. Under the hood, my server side APIs are all serverless, typically on Lambda. I don't want to maintain state on the server, hence the interest in an SPA.

But first things first, how do I compile Svelte into vanilla JS so that I can ship that JS bundle to Cloudfront?

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72336698/how-to-compile-a-svelte-file-to-javascript-from-the-command-line), there is no CLI tool to trigger compilation of Svelte->JS. I'm starting to think that I just ship the Svelte code to Cloudfront and the compilation happens under the hood...? Though this seems wrong

Comment: If you're using `sveltekit` just implement the static adapter. see [Static site generation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static)

Comment: If you're just using svelte you'll need to compile yourself, MDN has a [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) example: [Deployment and next steps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_deployment_next#a_look_behind_the_svelte_compilation_process)

Comment: Ah I was wondering if SvelteKit would be necessary. On that note, an AWS adapter is pre-built with a recommended architecture closely aligned with my use case https://github.com/MikeBild/sveltekit-adapter-aws

Comment: SvelteKit isn't necessary per se, but the adapter you linked to is specifically for sveltekit.